# Right Inverse of a surjective homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G,G'$ be groups, Let $\phi:G \longrightarrow G' $ an surjective homomorphism. So we know that exists  $f : G'\longrightarrow G$ and that $ \phi \  \circ  \ f = id_{G'} $. Is $f$ a homorphism?

Comment: If $\Phi\circ f=id_{G'}$ then $\Phi$ has to be surjective hence is bijective; then $f$ must be the unique inverse $\Phi^{-1}$ and the answer ist "yes". I'm not sure if this is what you want to ask.

Comment: Sorry I meant surjective ^^

Comment: Since there are in general several mappings $f$ satisfying $\phi\circ f=id_{G'}$, the correct question would be: does among these exist one which is a homomorphism? (The answer is still no, se below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Take the morphism $C_{p^2}\to C_p$ ($C_n$ denoting the cyclic group $\left< a\right>$ of order $n$ generated by $a$) determined by $a\mapsto a$. Then there is no (splitting) morphism $C_p\to C_{p^2}$ ($p$ any prime).

Comment: Why such a function cannot exist?

Comment: Let $a$ be a generating element of $C_{p^2}$ and $b$ be some (generating element) of $C_p$. Let $\phi: C_{p^2}\to C_p$ be determined by $\phi(a)=b$; then $\phi(a^p)=1$ and $\mathrm{ker}\phi=\{1,a^p,a^{2p},\dots, a^{(p-1)p}\}$. The image of a morphism  $f: C_p\to C_{p^2}$ is either trivial or a subgroup of $C_{p^2}$ of order $p$. The only subgroup of $C_{p^2}$ of order $p$ consists of the elements $1,a^p,a^{2p},\dots, a^{(p-1)p}$. In any case this gives that $\phi\circ f$ is the trivial (constant) morphism.

Answer (score 3):

In general no.

For example the homomorphism $\phi\colon\mathbb Z/4 \to \mathbb Z/2$ given by reducing modulo $2$ is surjective, but the only homomorphisms $f\colon\mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/4$ are the trivial homomorphism and the map $0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto 2$.  You can check that for either of these choices $\phi\circ f$ is the trivial zero homomorphism.

An $f$ which is also a homomorphism exists when $G$ is a [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of $G'$ and $\ker\phi$.